# bash colored text and piping

Tags: perl, bash

I have a Perl script that outputs some colored text under bash. For example, this will output a red string:

```
perl -e 'print "\e[1;31m RED \e[m"
```

When I pipe it to another program, e.g. vim `... | vim -` , I can see the color formating clutter-characters:

```
^[[1;31m RED ^[[m
```

and I want them to be skipped. It happens for example for `grep`, that you see colors in bash, but they are skipped when the output is redirected.

How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use [Term::ANSIColor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Term%3a%3aANSIColor) for generating the escape sequences, you can set the [`ANSI_COLORS_DISABLED`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Term%3a%3aANSIColor#ANSI_COLORS_DISABLED) environment variable to disable escape sequence generation).

You can use the `-t` file test to find out if the output is to a tty (or [detect if your script is being run interactively](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-find-out-if-I%27m-running-interactively-or-not%3f)).

Then, set the environment variable in the Perl script before any sequences are output.

Something like:

```
use IO::Interactive;

BEGIN { is_interactive() or $ENV{ANSI_COLORS_DISABLED} = 1 }
```

should do it.

Comment: You can test without IO::Interactive module: if (-t STDOUT) { $ENV{ANSI_COLORS_ENABLED} = 1 }

Comment: @RodrigoSiqueira I am not sure what the purpose of your comment is. My answer specifically points out *can use the -t file test to find out if the output is to a tty*. The `IO::Interactive` module provides something more. See the FAQ entry which is linked from my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to find out what kind of handle stdout is. I don't remember the details but it is possible to find out whether a handle points to a file, a pseudo tty (terminal window), or a pipe.

Comment: `-t FILEHANDLE` will tell you whether a filehandle is opened to a tty.

Answer (score 1):

For grep, grep detects that its output is not going to the terminal and does not create the escape sequences.

Another approach would be to use `sed` to strip out those escape sequences:

```
sed 's/\o033\[[0-9;]*m//'
```

(NOTE: There are a lot more [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) than this; but this should cover the colors.)

Comment: and it's even configurable, so if you need color codes in a piped stream you can have it.

Comment: Any idea how to detect it in Perl?

Comment: Yep, --color=always.  And the colors can be configured with environment variables...

Comment: `-t FILEHANDLE` will tell you whether a filehandle is opened to a tty.

Comment: perlfaq is relevant here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-find-out-if-I%27m-running-interactively-or-not%3f